# Integrating Keycloak with Java EE application

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to secure my java EE application running on a JBOSS server with Keycloak. To do so I made the following addition in web.xml file:

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I added the following dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and the below module in my jboss standalone.xml:

```
<extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-subsystem"/>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1"/>
```

Apart from this, I have followed all the directions given on keycloak.org like installing keycloak server, creating realm and a client followed by creating users. After doing this, when I click on login page of my application, it perfectly redirects to keycloak login page and once I login there, it redirects to my application login page. In case the user is already login on keycloak, directly the application login is displayed.

Now I want that in case the user logs into keycloak application, s/he does not need to login again to my application but he should be directed to home page since authentication has already been done by keycloak. To do this, do we need to maintain the authentication tokens in our database and validate these against the token generated by Keycloak or there is some other approach? I am clueless at this point after doing the above tasks.

Comment: Why do you have also a login page in your application ?

Comment: I will remove that but how will I maintain the mapping between keycloak users and application users in database. Apologies if you find this a lame question but my knowledge about keycloak is quite limited.

Comment: Don't worry there are no lame questions. Usually with Keycloak you don't manage your users in your app, KC handles that. But you could just have a mapping between the Keycloak User ID and your User ID if needed but this is out of scope of Keycloak.

Comment: Since mapping between the userIDs are not possible, will keycloak generate different authTokens for each user and we can maintain those AuthTokens in our database to identify which user is trying to login? If this is not the right approach, how will we be able to control the access of the web application as the menus in my application are shown based on different roles?

Comment: The token that Keyclaok delivers is a JWT , it contains all you need : roles, name, email ... I'm not sure I fully understand your issue.

Comment: The user that logs into my application has certain roles and I have set access controls based on those roles. Do I need to import all those users from my database into keycloak so that the JWT that keycloak generates can be used to identify the user that is trying to log in and I could control the access based on that? Do you have any demo where keycloak has been integrated with a Java EE application with SQL server as the backend database? That will give the complete picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154910/discussion-between-whywake-and-sebastien-blanc).